# Compare two arrays of objects to find matches

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out the best way to compare two different arrays of objects. Both arrays are identical in structure. e.g.:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [f_name] => Luis
        [id] => 1
        [rank] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [f_name] => Eden
        [id] => 2
        [rank] => 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [f_name] => Robin
        [id] => 4
        [rank] => 3
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [f_name] => Wayne
        [id] => 3
        [rank] => 4
    )
)
```

There are around 600 objects in the first array, and a variable number in the second array. I don't want to loop through the smaller array and unset any matches from the larger array, but that's the only way I can think of doing it. Is there a better way?

Would there be a better way to do this as I extract this from the database (mySQL)? I realise that is separate question, and I'll ask it accordingly if the general consensus is to do it there.

***Edit***

In response to the comments, the query is pretty unwieldy, and I have simplified the objects returned, but this is the gist of it:

Query 1 (larger result set)

```
SELECT `players`.`f_name`, `players`.`id`, `default_rankings`.`rank` FROM `default_rankings` 
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.`id` = `default_rankings`.`player_id` 
ORDER BY `default_rankings`.`rank` asc
```

Query 2 (smaller result set)

```
SELECT `players`.`f_name`, `players`.`id`, `player_rankings`.`rank` FROM `player_rankings` 
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.`id` = `player_rankings`.`player_id` 
WHERE `player_rankings`.`user_id` = '1' 
ORDER BY `player_rankings`.`rank` asc
```

***Edit***

Following on from @MarcB's comment, I changed my first query to this:

```
SELECT `players`.`f_name`, `players`.`id`, `default_rankings`.`rank` FROM  `default_rankings` 
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.`id` = `default_rankings`.`player_id`
WHERE `players`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `player_id` FROM `user_rankings` WHERE `user_id` = '1') 
ORDER BY `default_rankings`.`rank` asc
```

Which works great, as it doesn't mess up any limits and offsets once it's handed to the front end controller.

Comment: Expand on the DB usage as a condition or join might do it.

Comment: `select * from table1 where table1.id not in (select id from table2)`?

Comment: Actually, @MarcB was spot on with that comment. I don't really know how to mark that as an answer. What is the etiquette here? Do I add to my own question to answer it?

Comment: Either @MarcB can add it as an answer, or you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think that array_intersect() would be the way to go. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php -

Example from the PHP docs -

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);

// output
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Comment: I was trying to use `array_intersect()` but couldn't get it to play nicely with my object array, and I hadn't thought about how doing it this way would mess up my pagination. So I ended up following MarcB's advice. Thanks.